# what are the pull.rebase false & pull.ff true differences?

Tags: git

is there any difference in using

```
git config pull.rebase false     # merge (the default strategy)
```

and

```
git config pull.ff true
```

both commands fast-forwards if possible, and if it's not merge.

Which config should I use?

Comment: One disturbing point about your question : `pull.rebase false` and `pull.ff true` are both the default values for these config settings, which sort of moots the point "Which config should I use ?" of your question.

Comment: @LeGEC because git asking me to specify how to reconcile divergent branches

Answer (score 29, accepted):

While both these settings act on how `git pull` should behave when git, during a `git pull`, has to reconcile changes in your local branch with upstream changes, they don't turn the same knob.

- `pull.ff` can be set to `false | true | only`.
  It matches the cli options : `--no-ff | --ff | --ff-only`, and if any of these options is passed on the command line, the config setting is overlooked.

If set to `only`, `git pull` will refuse to do anything if the remote branch is not straight ahead of your local branch, so the `pull.rebase` setting will never kick in.

- `pull.rebase` can be set to `false | true | interactive | merges`.
  It matches the cli option `--rebase[=false|true|merges|interactive]`, and again: if any of these options is passed on the command line, the config setting is overlooked.

If it is set to something that says "use rebase to combine the changes" (e.g: `true|interactive|merges`), then a setting stating `--ff` or `--no-ff` has no effect -- there won't be a merge anyway.

---

*what should I use ?*

This question depends on context -- for example : if your work has a workflow which favors one action specifically, set the defaults to that action ; if you are used to a specific sequence of actions, set the defaults to your usage.

Instead of answering your question, I will describe how I work :

I personally don't like using `git pull`, because you get in one go "get the changes you don't know of from the central repo, and merge them with your work", without a chance to review the changes between the two steps.

I generally run :

1. `git fetch`
2. `git log --graph --oneline origin/master my/branch` (e.g : inspect the state of the remote branch I'm interested in)
3. run either `git rebase origin/master` or `git merge origin/master` (we happen to have a workflow which favors `rebase`, but anyways : I already have an idea of how complicated that action is going to be)

the difference with `git pull` is that at step 3, I can do :

- merge or rebase an *intermediate* commit of the remote branch , or an intermediate commit of my own branch,
- cherry-pick a specific commit to see what mess it would introduce,
- edit my branch *before* rebasing/merging (one common case: drop that commit which does almost the same thing as the bugfix added on master)
- ...

I have also set an alias for `pull --ff-only`, since that one is "harmless" (e.g: you know git will not mess up your code if you run it, it will either do the trivial thing or stop and say "this is not a fast-forward"), and use it to update branches which are not mine.

Answer (score 6):

> both commands fast-forwards if possible

Actually, [`pull.ff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullff) will *refuse* to pull if the tip of the current branch cannot be fast-forwarded, when the setting is set to `only`.

While `pull.rebase` simply instructs `pull` to make a merge (fast-forward or not).

Personally, I always use `git config --global pull.rebase true` in order to rebase (replay) my local commits (not yet pushed) on top of the refreshed remote tracking branch.

---

> what's the point of having to similar commands

Because both settings achieve different goals:

- set `pull.ff` to `only` disallows fast-forward `pull`: it is what to do on a *merge* `pull`.
- if `pull.rebase` is set to true, then `pull.ff` does not matter: if is about what to do on a `pull` (merge? or rebase?)

Comment: thanks, but "git config pull.ff true" will do the same as "git config pull.rebase false"? that's my question, just curious, what's the point of having to similar commands

Comment: @AlisherBaigazin Yes, but the point is you can set `pull.ff` to `only`, disallowing fast-forward pull. Hence the existence of that setting. By default, at `true`, it is does not prevent fast-forward, provided `pull.rebase` is set to `false`. If `pull.rebase` is set to `true`, then `pull.ff` does not matter.